# Image presheaf which is not a sheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, sheaf-theory

I read a proof which states that the kernel of a morphism between Sheaves is a sheaf. I can not realize the proof, and I have to read it again. It is written that the Image of a morphism between sheaves is not a sheaf necessarily, and gives this example:

$\exp: \cal{F} \rightarrow \cal{G}$, which sends $f$ to $exp(2\pi if)$. Now look at $\exp(\log z)=z=Id(z)$.

---

As I stated in the previous question, I am not comfortable with sheaves, and I can not get the point of the counter-example. Here I will say what I've realized:

In this example, we deal with the sheaf of rings of the "suitable" functions on the topological space $X$. But I do not which property should be replaced for the term "suitable". Analytic? Continues? Differentiable?

---

I can realize why that is a sheaf; for instance, let "suitable"=continues:

- To each open subset $U \subseteq X$, we can associate the ring of continuous functions $\cal{F}$$(U)$.
- For any open subsets $U_1 \subseteq U_2 \subseteq U_3$, we have restriction maps $\rho_{(U_i,U_j)}:$$\cal{F}$ $(U_i) \rightarrow $ $\cal{F}$$(U_j)$ (for $i \geq j$); such that: (1) $\rho_{(U_i,U_i)}$ is an identity of $U_i$, and (2) $\rho_{(U_3,U_1)}=\rho_{(U_2,U_1)} o \rho_{(U_3,U_2)}$.
- Given a family of open sets $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$ which is a cover of $U$, and a family of section $f_i \in \cal{F}$$(U_i)$, which are identical on every intersection. Then it is clear that there exists a unique section $f \in \cal{F}$$(U)$, which agrees with $f_i$ on $U_i$.

Am I check it truly?

---

Why that example is a counterexample to "an image presheaf which is not a sheaf"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what $\cal F$ and $\cal G$ are, but let's takes some topological
space $X$, let $\cal F$ be the sheaf of continuous complex functions on $X$
and $\cal G$ be the sheaf of continuous non-zero complex functions on $X$.
Your definition then makes sense as a sheaf homomorphism.

This map exp is a surjective map of sheaves, but its image as a *presheaf* is
not necessarily
the whole of $\cal G$. If the presheaf image is $\cal H$, then ${\cal H}(U)$
is the set of functions on $U$ with a continuous logarithm. If say $X=\Bbb C$
then ${\cal H}(\Bbb C-\{0\})\ne{\cal G}(\Bbb C-\{0\})$
since the function $z\mapsto z$ is continuous and nonzero on $\Bbb C-\{0\}$
but has no continuous logarithm on that set.

But exp is surjective as a map of *sheaves*. The image of exp is the sheaf
of functions on $X$ which *locally* have continuous logarithms, that is
all nonzero continuous functions, since a continuous nonzero function has
a continuous logarithm in some neighbourhood of any given point.

Comment: By reading your solution, I realized that I still do not understand the concept of "presheaf image". I mean that If the map $\exp$ is a surjective map of sheaves, then I conclude that the presheaf image is $\cal{G}$! Which is clearly in conflict with your proposition, so what is wrong with my conclusion? I think you point out that the sections for the identity map are not globally glueable. Am I right? I am almost new to the subject, and I am confused.

Comment: As I explained, the presheaf image is not $\cal G$, and I gave an example of a section of $\cal G$ that isn't in the  presheaf image of exp. @Neo

Comment: I thought that when we talk about the presheaf image (or sheaf image), we mean the image of the presheaf (or image of the sheaf). But it seems that I am mistaken. I am confused about the definition of **presheaf image** and **sheaf image**. Is it ok to ask another question about such a basic fact on the definition of presheaf image?

Comment: @Neo If you have a map of sheaves, it has an image as a map of presheaves, and an image of a map of sheaves. They may not be the same! The presheaf image may not be a sheaf; the sheaf image is its sheafification.